# R package for symbolic data analysis

Tags: r, clustering

Most methods for [symbolic data analyis](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470090162.html) are currently implemented in the SODAS software.

Are there any R packages for symbolic data except clamix and clusterSim?

Answer (score 2):

I've just found out that the package [symbolicDA](http://keii.ae.jgora.pl/symbolicDA/index.html) is about to appear on CRAN in a few months' time.

Answer (score 0):

Just from reading the link, it seems to me that there is probably some packages that do what you want in the machine learning view on CRAN http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

Hope this helps.